# Find Percent of Orders that were Returned in mysql

Tags: mysql, percentage

I am trying to find the percent of SKU's ordered that were returned. Here's what I have so far:

My tables are Orders and RMA

Orders Table:

```
create table Orders (OrderID int not null, CustomerID int, SKU VARCHAR(20), Description VARCHAR(50), primary key (OrderID), foreign key (CustomerID) references Customers(CustomerID));
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

```
    +-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| OrderID     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| CustomerID  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| SKU         | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Description | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

RMA table:

```
create table RMA (RMAID int not null, OrderID int, Step VARCHAR(50), Status VARCHAR(15), Reason VARCHAR(15), primary key (RMAID), foreign key (OrderID) references Orders(OrderID));

+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| RMAID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| OrderID | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Step    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Status  | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Reason  | varchar(15) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec) 

mysql> select SKU, Description, count(SKU) as Returned,
    -> (COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
    -> from Orders join RMA using (OrderID)
    -> group by SKU order by Percent desc;
```

I also ran a query to find % of SKU ordered

```
mysql> select SKU, Description, count(SKU) as Ordered,
    -> (COUNT(Orders.SKU)* 100 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Orders)) AS Percent
    -> From Orders Group by SKU order by Percent desc;

+------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| SKU        | Description                                        | Ordered | Percent |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
| BAS-48-1 C | Basic Switch 10/100/1000 BaseT 48 port             |    8385 | 22.0670 |
| ENT-48-40F | Enterprise Switch 40GigE SFP+ 48 port              |    6186 | 16.2798 |
| ENT-48-10F | Enterprise Switch 10GigE SFP+ 48 port              |    4329 | 11.3927 |
| BAS-08-1 C | Basic Switch  10/100/1000 BaseT 8 port             |    4285 | 11.2769 |
| ENT-24-10F | Enterprise Switch 10GigE SFP+ 24 Port              |    4275 | 11.2506 |
| ADV-24-10C | Advanced Switch 10GigE Copper 24 port              |    4178 | 10.9953 |
| ADV-48-10F | Advanced Switch 10 GigE Copper/Fiber 44 port coppe |    4174 | 10.9848 |
| ENT-24-40F | Enterprise Switch 40GigE SFP+ 24 port              |    2152 |  5.6635 |
| BAS-24-1 C | Basic Switch 10/100/1000 BaseT 24 port             |      34 |  0.0895 |
+------------+----------------------------------------------------+---------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

These are giving me the percent returned and percent ordered by SKU, but what I'd like to show is total ordered, total returned, and Percent returned group by SKU order by Percent descending.

The outcome I'd like would be:

```
SKU        | Ordered  | Returned | Percent_Returned
BAS-48-1 C    8385       8282          99
```

I thought I had it. The following got the Returned column right, but I can't figure out why the Ordered column increased.

```
 mysql> SELECT SKU,
    -> count(SKU) AS Ordered, count(RMA.OrderID) AS Returned,
    -> round(100*count(RMA.OrderID) / count(*)) AS Percent_Returned
    -> FROM Orders
    -> LEFT JOIN RMA USING (OrderID)
    -> GROUP BY SKU
    -> ORDER BY Percent_Returned DESC;
+------------+---------+----------+------------------+
| SKU        | Ordered | Returned | Percent_Returned |
+------------+---------+----------+------------------+
| ENT-48-10F |    4346 |     4287 |               99 |
| BAS-08-1 C |    4308 |     4248 |               99 |
| BAS-48-1 C |    8422 |     8282 |               98 |
| ENT-24-10F |    4296 |     4231 |               98 |
| ENT-24-40F |    2159 |     2121 |               98 |
| ENT-48-40F |    6212 |     6118 |               98 |
| ADV-24-10C |    4189 |     4122 |               98 |
| ADV-48-10F |    4198 |     4124 |               98 |
| BAS-24-1 C |      34 |       33 |               97 |
+------------+---------+----------+------------------+
9 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Comment: Please provide a schema (e. g. CREATE TABLE statements), example data and desired output.

Comment: Hi Mihe! I'll add to the original, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the following query should result in the desired output:

```
SELECT SKU, 
       count(*) AS Ordered, count(DISTINCT RMA.OrderID) AS Returned,
       round(100*count(DISTINCT RMA.OrderID) / count(*)) AS Percent_Returned     
  FROM Orders 
       LEFT JOIN RMA USING (OrderID) 
GROUP BY SKU
ORDER BY Percent_Returned DESC;
```

It's a little more readable using a CTE:

```
WITH totals AS (
    SELECT SKU, count(*) AS Ordered, count(DISTINCT RMA.OrderID) AS Returned
    FROM Orders LEFT JOIN RMA USING (OrderID) 
    GROUP BY SKU
)
SELECT SKU, Ordered, Returned, round(100*Returned / Ordered) AS Percent_Returned
  FROM totals
 ORDER BY Percent_Returned;
```

Comment: Hi Mihe! This is extremely helpful, thank you! Your first query shows what I'm striving for, but the quantity ordered and returned seems to be different from what I found. For example, SKU BAS-48-1 C I found 8385 ordered and this found 8422. I could not get the 2nd query to run, it the following error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'totals AS (SELECT SKU, count(*) AS Ordered, count(DISTINCT RMA.OrderID) AS Retur' at line 1

Comment: The second query requires MySQL 8. Regarding the counts: perhaps you want/need count(distinct SKU) instead of count(*)?

Comment: Mihe, I figured out what I did differently. I just used JOIN where you used LEFT JOIN. I've got it now. I appreciate you!

Comment: I thought I had it, returned column is now correct. I can't figured out why the Ordered column quantity increased. I added results in the original.

Comment: Sorry, I'm on the road. The query depends on the type of relationship between the tables. If there's at most one record in table RMA, then the it should be correct. The left join uses all records from table Orders and joins them with the existing records in table RMA. If there's no corresponding record in RMA for an order, then the joined values are NULL.